# Why do all subclasses only use spells from the Player's Handbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, archetype

Some of the subclasses from classes like the sorcerer, cleric, warlock, paladin and druid gain addditional spells based on the subclass that they choose. These sometimes involve spells that aren't usually part of the class' spell list.
However, when looking through the subclasses in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, I've noticed that **all the subclasses only gain additional spells from the *Player's Handbook***. Once I noticed the pattern, I checked subclasses from other sources and noticed that they too only use spells that are in the *Player's Handbook*.

Is this an intentional design? It seems like a waste to make 50-or-so new spells, to not use a single one in any of your subclasses. I could imagine you don't want to cross-reference spells from multiple expansion books other than the PHB, but once you've got the book, you've got both the spells and the subclasses, right?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we have decided as a community to make [questions about designer intent off-topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/are-questions-about-rule-intent-on-topic).

Comment: That's a really interesting observation.  You could try poking Jeremy Crawford or WoTC on Twitter about it.

Comment: This is a fantastically interesting question in my opinion. It's just not right for this site. We can't answer why designers chose or did something because none of us designed the game! We're having a bit of a chat about it in our [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/trpg-general-chat) and you're welcome to join in on that though!